# iOS turn-based vs real-time multiplayer connectivity options

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

I am looking into multiplayer connectivity options for a two player game and wondering what options are available to use. I've read up on a bunch of stuff online but still couldn't figure this out. I've done a tutorial with GKSession from GameKit.h, but I'm confused on whether Game Center and GameKit are the same thing.

What are some connectivity options for both a turn-based and real-time two player game? Are there any benefits for either styles with these connectivity options?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely agree with @WendiKidd -- you need to decide what type of game you are making to determine the technology to use. Game Center won't directly solve this for you, it will just provide an API for "extra" that you can hook into.

That being said, turn-based is probably easier to write and has a few more options for implementation. You'll need/want to setup a server in the middle that can act as the central arbiter for the different players. E.g., player one submits a move, which gets sent to your server. Then when player two logs in/plays, the game would check against the server for updates and then affect the game state accordingly.

Comment: Ok, sorry I should have worded my question better. I havent't decided on the style yet, but I just wanted to explore my options. If I want to go with the real-time approach, is GameCenter alone sufficient or would I still need an intermediary server? Thanks.

Comment: Game Center doesn't provide that sort of functionality -- it's for some of the "niceties" on top of your game. You'll need to look in to your own infrastructure for synchronizing state between the different players.

Answer (score 2):

Game Center is the customer-facing name of the services Apple provides. GameKit is the framework that Apple provides for developers to implement Game Center functionality.

Whether or not you make a turn-based or real-time game really depends on the type of game you're making.